# Writing Calculator class into a "Command Line Calculator" program (Java)

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, calculator

Here is the relevant part of the main program from the assignment:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

        int characters = args.length;
        if (characters < 3) 

            System.out.println("You did not type in a calculation!");

        else if (characters % 2 == 0)

            System.out.println("Invalid number of command line parameters.");

        else {

            Calculathor counter = new Calculathor();
            counter.count(args);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only allowed to write the class shown below (Calculator) into the program in the assignment. I just can't figure out how to get a printable result from the calculation.

I presume the switch statement is working as intended in receiving the operator from user's input and putting it to use but I need something else to get the actual result.

```
class Calculator {

int result;
int i = 0;

    String[] args;

    void count(String[] args) {


    switch (args[i].charAt(i)) {
    case '+': result = Integer.parseInt(args[i]) +
    Integer.parseInt(args[i+2]);
    break;

    case '-': result = Integer.parseInt(args[i]) -
    Integer.parseInt(args[i+2]);
    break;
    }

System.out.println("\nResult of the calculation " + args[0] + " + " + args[2] + " + " + args[4] + " - " + args[6] + " is " + result);

    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting the result value int the result variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some pointers:

```
Calculathor counter = new Calculathor();
```

should probably be

```
Calculator counter = new Calculator();
```

And, a [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is more or less a substitute for if-elseif-else-statements (see the linked tutorial for clarification).

You probably want to [loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) over each argument and check if it's a number or an operator. For example:

```
for(String arg: args){
    ///Code 
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    //Code
}
```

Within this loop you can have a switch statement that checks if the current arg is an int or an operator. You could, for example, increment `i` by more than one to do one summation at each iteration, e.g `i+=3` instead of `i++` (Warning: Think it through so you don't get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`)

Also, there's probably no need for `charAt` since each arg is a string of length 1 (I assume). If you have one big string you probably only want to loop over `args[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you iterate over the args-Array, and increment i while looping (for example, by applying a for-loop)?

Do you supply enough cmd-arguments to your programm?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't want to do your assignment, but I do see a couple of things that could be causing you problems:

You never change the value of i:

```
int i = 0;
```

This means your switch statement is going to work on the first character. For example if your args are: 2+3, 2 will be evaluated. Since 2 is neither a + or a - and because you don't have a default case in your switch statement, you won't see any output.

Your method doesn't return a number. See mabbas answer for more details